# Create EKRecurrenceRule using setPositions

Tags: ios, swift, ekrecurrencerule

**Simple version of question:**

How do I create an EKRecurrenceRule object using the `setPositions` field?

**Longer version of question:**

I created an event with an `EKRecurrenceRule` object with the following code in my app:

```
let recurrenceRule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWithFrequency: .Yearly ,
                                      interval: 1,
                                      daysOfTheWeek: [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.Friday)],
                                      daysOfTheMonth: nil ,
                                      monthsOfTheYear: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                                      weeksOfTheYear: nil,
                                      daysOfTheYear: nil,
                                      setPositions: [-1.0],
                                      end: nil)
```

After creating the event in my app, the output in the built-in calendar looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `setPosition` is reading as nil. But oddly enough, I can output the `setPosition` property of the `recurrenceRule` object in my app and get the value i set of `-1` like this:

```
if let setPosition = recurrenceRule.setPositions?[0]{
     print("event set position: \(setPosition))")
} else {
     print("event set position: nil)")
}
```

When creating an event with the exact same recursion using the built in calendar, the output looks as desired:

[image]

But when i run the same outputting code as above on the event created inside the built-in calendar, the `setPositions` output `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let recurrenceRule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWithFrequency: .Monthly ,
                                      interval: 1,
                                      daysOfTheWeek: [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.Friday)],
                                      daysOfTheMonth: nil ,
                                      monthsOfTheYear: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                                      weeksOfTheYear: nil,
                                      daysOfTheYear: nil,
                                      setPositions: [-1.0],
                                      end: nil)
```

Will get you once a month on the months mentioned in "monthsOfTheYear". What you currently have is once a year